# How to set iScroll scrollbars to hide when has not focused

Tags: focus, scrollbar, iscroll

I'm using iScroll 5 and i defined custom scrollbars and set interactiveScrollbars to true. so it's work like a charm but i want force it to hide scrollbars when it has not focus and show them any time mouse or touch move on.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `fadeScrollbars` option to `true`.
This will make the scrollbar and indicator fade away when they are not used.

```
var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
    /* iScroll Options */
     scrollbars: true,
     interactiveScrollbars: true,
     fadeScrollbars: true
});
```

Comment: unfortunately it seems IScroll can't work on Flex scenario. i tried nicescroll too and for now i stopped using any kind of this but about your answer i'll check it asap and if that worked i will accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @QMaster thanks for the reply, I'll leave this question open. For now, I just use `fadeScrollbars` on my project.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll back to scroll world asap :)

Answer (score 0):

`hideScrollbar: true` property is important for firefox browser, to restrict weird scrollbar issues.

```
var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
  /* iScroll Options */
  scrollbars: true,
  interactiveScrollbars: true,
  hideScrollbar: true, /* this is important for Firefox browser */
  fadeScrollbars: true
})
```